# Including variables in sql statement Nodejs sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite

how do we include variable in query statement.  I am trying to include {arg} variable after the WHERE

```
const CustomFunction = (arg) =>{
db.all("SELECT * FROM default_table WHERE mytype={arg}", (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const CustomFunction = (arg) =>{
db.all("SELECT * FROM default_table WHERE mytype=" + arg, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.all(`SELECT * FROM default_table WHERE mytype =  ${args}`,(err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
```

See also [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/)